# Understanding MKCoordinateFromMapPoint behaviour

Tags: ios, mkmapview, cllocation

In a location based app we use MKMapPoints to store locations, for example the current user location.

When we try use this location on a MKMapView, to set the region that is initially displayed (zoomed in on the user) we convert this to a CLLocationCoordinate2D

There's a convernience method for that: namenly: MKCoordinateForMapPoint, but during testing this gives strange results.

```
  MKMapPoint mapPoint = MKMapPointMake(51.96, 6.3); // My area ;)
  CLLocationCoordinate2D automagicCoordinate = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(mapPoint);
  CLLocationCoordinate2D manualCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(mapPoint.x, mapPoint.y);
```

I would expect both the automagicCoordinate and the manualCoordinate to be exactply the same.
but when I inspect it in the debugger I get the following result:

```
automagicCoordinate.latitude = (CLLocationDegrees) 85.05
automagicCoordinate.longitude = (CLLocationDegrees) -179.99

manualCoordinate.latitude = (CLLocationDegrees) 51.96
manualCoordinate.longitude = (CLLocationDegrees) 6.3
```

How come the coordinate created with the method is incorrect?

Answer (score 7):

An `MKMapPoint` is not a latitude and longitude.  If it was, you wouldn't need a function to "convert" it to coordinates.

As the Location Awareness Programming Guide explains in the [Understanding Map Geometry](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH3-SW5) section:

> A map point is an x and y value on the Mercator map projection. Map points are used for many map-related calculations instead of map coordinates because they simplify the mathematics involved in the calculations.

The [documentation for MKMapPoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009734-CH1-SW2) is clearer:

> If you project the curved surface of the globe onto a flat surface,
>   what you get is a two-dimensional version of a map where longitude
>   lines appear to be parallel. ...
>
> The actual units of a map point are tied to the underlying units used
>   to draw the contents of an MKMapView, but you should never need to
>   worry about these units directly. ...
>
> When saving map-related data to a file, you should always save
>   coordinate values (latitude and longitude) and not map points.

The map point `51.96, 6.3` corresponds to a coordinate at the top-left of the map projection.  If you want to work with coordinates (latitude, longitude), use a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` to avoid confusion.

(You can technically use an `MKMapPoint` struct to store your coordinate values but then they don't need to be converted to coordinates and the wrong type usage will just lead to confusion.)